# Type Error in PyCharm Using "Pandas" and "Seaborn"

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, seaborn, typeerror

I am currently using Python with the IDE PyCharm to plot a data frame generated in pandas with seaborn. I am appliing the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

netflix_stocks = pd.read_csv("NFLX.csv")
dowjones_stocks = pd.read_csv("DJI.csv")
netflix_stocks_quarterly = pd.read_csv("NFLX_daily_by_quarter.csv")

# rename columns
netflix_stocks.rename(columns = {'Adj Close': 'Price'}, inplace = True)
dowjones_stocks.rename(columns = {'Adj Close': 'Price'}, inplace = True)
netflix_stocks_quarterly.rename(columns = {'Adj Close': 'Price'}, inplace = True)


# visualizing the netflix quarterly data
ax = plt.subplot()
sns.violinplot(data = netflix_stocks_quarterly, x = "Quarter", y = "Price")
ax.set_title("Distribution of 2017 Netflix Stock Prices by Quarter")
plt.xlabel("Business Quarters in 2017")
plt.ylabel("Closing Stock Price")

plt.savefig("Distribution of 2017 Netflix Stock Prices by Quarter.png")
plt.show()
```

which leads me to the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 459, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/testproject/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    sns.violinplot(data = netflix_stocks_quarterly, x = "Quarter", y = "Price")
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 2408, in violinplot
    plotter.plot(ax)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 1043, in plot
    self.draw_violins(ax)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 801, in draw_violins
    self.draw_box_lines(ax, violin_data, support, density, i)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 967, in draw_box_lines
    ax.scatter(center, q50,
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4487, in scatter
    self.add_collection(collection)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2242, in add_collection
    self._unstale_viewLim()
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 776, in _unstale_viewLim
    self.autoscale_view(**{f"scale{name}": scale
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2932, in autoscale_view
    handle_single_axis(
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2895, in handle_single_axis
    x0, x1 = locator.nonsingular(x0, x1)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1654, in nonsingular
    return mtransforms.nonsingular(v0, v1, expander=.05)
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "D:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 462, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
python-BaseException
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```

For some reason, the same code works under jupyter notebook. I am importing pandas, matplotlib and seaborn in the following versions:

[versions of pckages imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrIxk.png)

Further, I created a project using a virtual environment as follows:

[project creation with a virtual environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aImBn.png)

Since the dataframes have no "empty" entries or those, for which the data type must be changed I cannot figure the reason out. The dataframe, which should be plotted looks like:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGqGN.png)

I appreciate any advice!

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: same python environment for Jupyter notebook and IDE? also please post a link to the actual data rather than a picture so that people can recreate the issue

Comment: Hi! The *.csv files can be found at https://github.com/jonasbauer192/CODECADEMY-Capstone-Project-Netflix-Data
Further, I use the jupyter notebook with miniconda and PyCharm with VirtualEnv. But I also tried using the Conda environment in PyCharm which does lead to the same error.

Comment: I just used Python 3.9.8 instead of 3.10.1 and it worked without problems for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved it downgrading the numpy package.
I was using 1.22.3 and changed to 1.22.2.

pip3 uninstall numpy

then

pip3 install numpy==1.22.2

Comment: Correct second command is:
```python
pip3 install numpy==1.22.2 ```